# Vue Test Utils use input field value in event handler function

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I am trying to write a test for a Vue input to ensure that a Vuex action is called when the input does the 'input' action:

```
<CustomInput id="quote-input" @input="myFunction"/>
```

Here is a version of the function:

```
myFunction(value) { this.myVuexAction({column: 'myColumnId', value: this.formatInput(value.trim())})}
```

The formatInput function is trimming content after a dot.

```
stripQuoteVersion(quoteNumber) {
 return quoteNumber.substring(0, quoteNumber.indexOf('.'))
}
```

This code is working when running in the browser but when I try to write a test for it, Vue Test Utils is sending an `Event` object to my event handler function, which makes sense according to the [docs](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger). My test is failing because the `Event` object cannot execute the `trim()` method because it is not a `String`. How can I send the text in the input to my function in the test?

My test looks like:

```
describe('QbtSearchBox', () => {
  test('myTest', async () => {
    const testSubject = mount(MyComponent, {
      store, localVue,
    })
    const quoteNumberInput = testSubject.find('#quote-input')
    quoteNumberInput.element.value = '1234567.2'
    await quoteNumberInput.trigger('input')
    await testSubject.vm.$nextTick()

    expect(myActions.myVuexAction).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

I have also tried this test with:

`await quoteNumberInput.trigger('input', {value: quoteNumberInput.element.value})`

and used
`myFunction(value) { this.myVuexAction({column: 'myColumnId', value: this.formatInput(value.value.trim())})}` 
which works in the test but not when running the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the event emit like following.

```
await quoteNumberInput.vm.$emit('input', '1234567.2')
```

Instead of

```
await quoteNumberInput.trigger('input')
```